# Reading CSV File from IBM MQ

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

What I am trying to achieve is to read a `csv` file from the queue through a java application. I would like to know if the data in queue is stored as a byte or the `csv` file is uploded directly.

Comment: Interesting. And what have you done so far to get there?

Comment: Hi I have just made a connection bean for MQ and I can send and receive data from it ,But I am not sure as to how to receive File type from MQ and whether I would get a file format or a byte stream from MQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQ does not care what you put in the message body. It can be simple text, stream of bytes, some structured data etc. So it's all up to the application how it wants handle the message body. The message body will be stream of bytes but MQ can convert the bytes to text format.

MQ on it's own does not send/receive files. Your application has to read data from the file into a buffer, set the buffer as message body and send the message. On the receiver side, your application has to receive message, retrieve the message body and write it to a file.

You can also look at MQ Managed File Transfer product.

Comment: Ok I get this,so it depends on us which format we place the data as...and fetch it...ok now if u can help onthis which is the best format taht I can use to place that data which I get from MQ into database.